# Cordova App and Manifold JS to load external URL

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net-mvc, cordova, manifoldjs

I have an MVC5 web app created with an external URL.  Basically I want to use a webview method to load in this external URL and take advantage of Push notifications etc.

I cannot get the app to run an external URL.  I have changed the `<content src="www.mydomain.com/Account/Login" />` in the config file. The application fails to debug with the error `Error DEP10402: Could not locate the start page. You may need to build your project.`

Any direction would be appreciated.

**Edit**
Here is my config, ps: added square brackets around http:// i.e. [http://] for stack overflow to allow the edit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget id="TTL" version="0.0.1" xmlns="[http://]www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="[http://]cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Toptipsterleagues</name>
  <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
  <content src="[http://]www.myDomain.com/Account/Login" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <access hap-rule="yes" origin="[http://]www.myDomain.com/Account/Login" />
    <allow-navigation hap-rule="yes" href="[http://]www.myDomain/Account/Login" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <access hap-rule="yes" origin="[http://]www.myDomain.com/Account/Login" />
  </platform>
  <preference name="Orientation" value="default" />
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
  <platform name="windows">
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
  </platform>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" version="1.2.1" />
  <vs:platformSpecificValues xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">
    <vs:platformSpecificWidget id="TTL" platformName="windows">
      <vs:name>TTL</vs:name>
    </vs:platformSpecificWidget>
  </vs:platformSpecificValues>
  <preference name="WindowsStoreDisplayName" value="TTL" />
</widget>
```